# Jinja equivalent to __file__?

Tags: python, jinja2

I would like to record the full path to my template in its output, much like the `__FILE__` macro expands to the current file in C.

I've tried the `{{ self._TemplateReference__context.name }}` trick, but this doesn't work when extending templates.  If A extends from B and A is rendered, then `self._TemplateReference__context.name` will evaluate to A's path always (even inside B).

What is equivalent to the `__FILE__` macro for jinja?